# How were the curls on this monogram done?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

Sorry if this is a bad question.
I've just finished an adobe illustrator course so my skills are extremely limited. 
I'd like to make a monogram but I'm not sure what the best process would be. (e.g. Taking a letter "N" font and modifying it, or making one from scratch)

Heres one I found on dribbble which I liked, but I'm struggling to figure out how it was done.

[image: N monogram]

I tried taking a letter N from a font, expanding it, and then trying to make adjustments using the direct selection tool to no avail.

I also tried creating an "N" with the pen tool, but couldn't get the uniformity right on both curls - they never looked even.

Lastly, I took the rectangle tool and rounded it off, placed it at a 45 degree angle to make the centre "oblong". Then I tried to use the pen tool for the curls, by doing one side and copying it to the other.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you don't need to use pen tool to create curls rather create the curls with the circle and delete the quater and make sure your stroke cap is set to Round

Here's a quick tutorial on this:

[image]

After creating your logo you can Expend your object and can use pathfinder to merge all shape in to one shape and then you can also apply some artistic effects from filter menu.

Comment: You know it would be easier if you used mirror + 1 for the effort anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You could redraw it and use `Stroke`. It would make drawing and aligning the lines a bit easier. This will not work for all situations, but for this specific one... maybe...

1. Use thin font as a guide to draw the N

   - I used Bariol - Thin.

   [image]

   - Draw the orange line on top of it with the `Pen tool`
     [image]
   - After this you can get rid of the original N.
2. Now you can easily draw a circle and snap move/snap it to the end point.

   [image]
3. With `Direct selection tool`, click the bottom right of the circle and delete it.

   [image]
4. Select the touching end points with `Direct selection tool` and join them `Cmd+J`
5. Use `Pen tool` to extend the circle inwards, if you want to

   [image]
6. In `Window > Stroke` adjust the stroke `weight` and change `Cap` and `Corner` to rounded.

   [image]

From then on it should be pretty straight forward to align stuff and round the corners even more, if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like this was just one shape, then flipped upside down and backwards.

Like this:

[image: n is two]

If you combine that with Rishab's technique, I suspect you'll be able to mimic this style.